# Invert Laplace Transform with Heaviside function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem, integral-transforms

I'm solving the following boundary value problem
$$
y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1, \quad u(x, 1)=1=u(0, y) .
$$

I've derived that
$\bar{u}(p, y)=p^{-2}+p^{-1}-p^{-2} y^{-p}$, however, I have no idea how to invert the last term. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the method of characteristics to solve the problem? This is straightforward.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\! \left(\frac{y^{-p}}{p^{2}},p,x\right)=\left(x-\ln\! \left(y\right)\right) \mathrm{H}\! \left(x-\ln\! \left(y\right)\right)$

with H(x) the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse Laplace transform of $\bar{u}(p, y)=p^{-2}+p^{-1}-p^{-2} y^{-p}$ with $p \to x$ gives

$$u \left(x,y\right)\mapsto 1+x-\left(x-\ln\! \left(y\right)\right)\cdot \mathrm{H}\! \left(x-\ln\! \left(y\right)\right), x \ge 0, y \ge 1$$

and $H(z)$ the Heaviside step function.

Visualization:
[image: Invert Laplace Transform]